# How to add and retrieve user data from FBX using python

Tags: python, fbx

I've been messing around for a few hours now and I'm a bit baffled on how I can 1. Add user data to an existing FBX file using python, and 2. Get known user data from and FBX file using python?

```
import os
import sys
import FbxCommon
import fbx

f = "C:\Users\john\test.fbx"


def fbx_user_data(filepath):
    fbxManager, fbxScene = FbxCommon.InitializeSdkObjects()
    FbxCommon.LoadScene(fbxManager, fbxScene, filepath)

    sceneInfo = fbxScene.GetSceneInfo()
    ......
```

Comment: FBX is the devil.